# Create One Column from Six different Columns Where all the columns for a row contain a null value except for one

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

The table includes a natural key in the form of a project number.

[image: Current Table]

[image: Ideal outcome]

Comment: And your attempt is where?  You also haven't asked a question, but rather just told us what to do.  We are here to help, not do your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EST = 1 THEN 'EST'
         WHEN INI = 1 THEN 'INI'
         WHEN AD = 1 THEN 'AD'
         WHEN DEV = 1 THEN 'DEV'
         WHEN UAT = 1 THEN 'UAT'
         WHEN IMP = 1 THEN 'IMP'
    END AS [Status]
FROM table
```